# Cannot insert the value NULL into column CreationTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Runtime Exception :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreationTime', table
>   'MyTables'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTables] (LegacyId, CreationTime)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.[IPLID], a.[inputdate] 
    FROM 
        [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] AS a
```

Can you tell me how to insert custom date like `01/01/2000` when `a.[inputdate]` is `Null` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just wrap in an `ISNULL`:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTables] (LegacyId,CreationTime)
SELECT DISTINCT a.[IPLID],ISNULL(a.[inputdate], '01/01/2000')
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] as a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISNULL function.

```
INSERT INTO [MyTables] (LegacyId,CreationTime)
SELECT DISTINCT a.[IPLID],ISNULL(a.[inputdate], '01/01/2000') FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables2] as a
```